# Bypassing the engine immobiliser with a microprocessor?

Tags: nissan, immobilizer, micra, by-pass

I have a K13 nissan micra 2014, it comes with a engine immobiliser that has a chip in the key.
I am from a Electronics background so excuse any mistakes i make, but would like to be able to start it remotely and as well have push button start. For this i would like to bypass the immobiliser.
From what i can tell it reads the data off the chip and sends it to the ECU.
Could i rig a microprocessor like a arduino to just send the same data to the ECU
and if so how would i go about doing that.

Also how could i bypass the wheel lock.

if not can how could i go about getting this done while being safe.

Thanks

Comment: As you have an electronics background, you should be able to work out the data sent then program the arduino to send similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to make a bypass with a loophole? aren't you afraid that your car could be stolen in the same way? or are you trying to get the neighbor's car? :|

The way you ask to bypass the wheel-lock, bypass immobilizer is concerning me.

You can however to create a similar device (wheel lock and immobilizer) with your own program and Arduino. But you need to understand basic programming in Arduino, and electronic.

However, for bypass-ing the original device, you need to understand how to reverse engineering. And I must say this is un-ethical which you can do an unresponsible thing or two.

This question is similar to you asking "how to hack Facebook" is pretty much hilarious.

Comment: yes i see the concern, i would not be able to get into someone else vehicle without the information in the chip right? all im asking is how to keep the secret in my rom and send it when the microprocessor gets a similar ok from other secure sources.

wheel lock because else i can't put in a push to start if the steering wheel is still locked

this is project feels like it would take hours to do, not something that could be done quick enough to steal a vehicle

Comment: as I said in my answer "However, for bypass-ing the original device, you need to understand how to reverse engineering."